# How to get Access Token from Local Storage in Console using ANGULAR6?

Tags: console, console.log, angular6

I save the response in local storage in console using angular6. Response contain (Id token, access token , JWT token) I want access token for user authentication. How I get this from local storage using angular.[Here is the Access Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZAqN.png)

Comment: look at this and adjust the line that get the token https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970446/http-error-handling-in-angular-6/50970853#50970853

Answer (score 3):

Let's say u have stored the server response with the key called `Token:` in the local storage.

```
var accessTokenObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Token:"));
console.log(accessTokenObj);
```